# Extract changed entities of a specific type when calling SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

DbContext:

```
public class AppContext : DbContext, IAppContext
{
    public AppContext()
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

I've implemented in-memory caching such that all `Users` are loaded into memory. GET requests fetch `Users` from this in-memory cache.

I'd like to "hook into" the `AppContext` to detect when a `User` or multiple `Users` have been modified when calling `SaveChanges()`, so I can push those changed entities into the Cache service for cache synchronization.

Ideally, I'd be able to do something like this from within the `AppContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelUpdate(SomeContextClass contextThing)
{
     IEnumerable<User> changedUsers = contextThing.ExtractChanges<User>();
     customCache.Sync(changedUsers); // handle updates, inserts, deletes in my custom cache
}
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Look at `DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries`.

Comment: @GertArnold What overridable method can I tie this into? Is there something like `OnModelUpdate` available? EF6

Comment: `SaveChanges(async)`. It only matters if entries were actually saved successfully.

Comment: @GertArnold if I override SaveChanges, won't I be inserting null primary keys into my cache whenever entities are added? Any way to prefetch the new PK? Or alternatively tie into some kind of `AfterSaveChanges`?

Comment: DIsregard - looks like the PK is already assigned by the time SaveChanges is called, somehow. If you'd like to create an answer for this, I can mark it as accepted, otherwise I can answer myself.

Answer (score 1):

@GertArnold feel free to copy/paste this into an answer that I'll accept if you'd like credit!

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var selectedEntityList = ChangeTracker.Entries()
                                .Where(x => x.Entity is User &&
                                (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified || x.State == EntityState.Deleted));

        foreach (var entity in selectedEntityList)
        {
            User user = (User)entity.Entity;

            if (entity.State == EntityState.Added)
                UserCache.AddNewUser(user);
            else if (entity.State == EntityState.Modified)
                UserCache.UpdateExistingUser(user);
            else if (entity.State == EntityState.Deleted)
                UserCache.DeleteExistingUser(user);
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Giving the hints was the easiest part. Really. It's your answer.